# Integrating Angular.js with Node.js (Express+Tower.js)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, towerjs, total.js

I am new to node. I very much like approach of AngularJS. I like what I see in towerjs.

Has Anyone wired the two together? I have in mind tower primarily for backend api/rest and angular for clientside.

Comment: By now, I'm sure you'll have what you need. But since this post help me a lot here you have my solution  http://techblog.appirio.com/2012/11/tutorial-creating-angularjs-app-with.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm especially not familiar with tower.js, but from the docs it looks like it might not be practical to use the two together. There is quite a bit of overlap in the things AngularJS provides and the things tower.js provides (especially models, views, and controllers on the client).

I've written on [how to use AngularJS with a RESTful API provided by Express on my blog](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html). Maybe that can help you get started.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your observations AND your blog with example code. It is invaluable for anyone cutting their teeth on these new tools. My question re tower.js was motivated by a desire to find best/better practices for more robust JSON/CRUD implementations. In particular MV(C/W) in cases where you would have several table/collections, ie, users/contacts/places/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Tower is for the server-side while angular is on the client right?

So what you could try what is mentioned [here](http://gelnior.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/how-to-quickly-start-a-single-page-application-with-node-js/). Just replace railway with tower.

You could check this brunch.io [skelleton](https://github.com/scotch/angular-brunch-seed) that uses angularjs.

Hope this comes in handy mate!

Comment: Tower works on both client and server side , Check out Tower's author comments here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9904446/286588

Answer (score 1):

As things are evolving very fast, there are some major update.

For example, a framework named Total.js has made much work to make Angular.js work in hand with Node.js.

Please have a look at their web site http://www.totaljs.com/totalstack/ and at the 6 (!) example they provide on how to use it : https://github.com/totaljs/examples.

Pretty amazing! Hope that helps!

Note: I have no affiliation with Total.js at all.